# Overview which Azure personal access token is used when and how often?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

how can I see which personal access tokens have been used when and how often?
We have created a too big list of token and would like to get a feeling  which token can be revoked.

Thank you

Comment: Hi. This is not answering my above question but if that is the only thing available I guess I have to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A personal access token (PAT) is used as an alternate password to authenticate into Azure DevOps.

We do not have this feature to record where and when you use the password (PAT) in Azure DevOps.

But for this `would like to get a feeling which token can be revoked.`

Users receive two notifications during the lifetime of a PAT - one upon creation and the other **seven days before the expiration**.

Seven days before your PAT expires, you receive a notification similar to the following example.

[image]